# Is it possible to bypass ArrayMap.containsKey()

Tags: java, android

I need to pass "contact_id" to this method but there is a check that prevents this column from being updated. Can you see anyway I can bypass it and update contact_id column as one of the columns in `values`

```
      // ANDROID CODE
public static final String CONTACT_ID = "contact_id";

private int updateRawContacts(ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            boolean callerIsSyncAdapter) {
        if (values.containsKey(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " should not be included " +
                    "in content values. Contact IDs are assigned automatically");
        }
        if (!callerIsSyncAdapter) {
            selection = DatabaseUtils.concatenateWhere(selection,
                    RawContacts.RAW_CONTACT_IS_READ_ONLY + "=0");
        }
        int count = 0;
        final SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.get().getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(Views.RAW_CONTACTS,
                Projections.ID, selection,
                selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                long rawContactId = cursor.getLong(0);
                updateRawContact(db, rawContactId, values, callerIsSyncAdapter,
                        /* callerIsMetadataSyncAdapter =*/false);
                count++;
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return count;
    }

// MY CODE
ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(RAW_CONTACTS_URI)
                .withValue(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts._ID);
```

Comment: You are updating a record in a db table, right?  Is contact_id the key for the record?

Comment: I do not see an `ArrayMap` in your code. I do see a `containsKey()` call, but that is on a `ContentValues`, not an `ArrayMap`. Perhaps you have the wrong code in the question, or the wrong title.